# javascript object creation for js remoting

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

Hi I am trying to use a `RemoteAction` function from `js remoting`.The remote function accepts a custom object,so I need to pass it from javascript.For this I m creating a javascript object with all fields of custom object.

```
function my_object__c(){
   this.id = null;
   this.name = null
   ------------
   more fields here
   ------------
}
```

The values of id, name and all other fields are binded to vf page's inputFields like this :

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!myObj.Name}"></apex:inputfield>
```

is there a easier way to access these values and use them in js object `my_object__c`.I can only think of travesering the `dom` and get these based on ids.

Second,can the `RemoteFunction` accept multiple parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohith did a good job pointing you to the [documentation for JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) for what is supported.

To get the values into your JavaScript object you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make it very easy.

Either put jQuery in a static resource or hotlink to one of the [CDN hosted copies](http://jquery.com/download/).
Here's how to do use jQuery with the static resources:

Put jQuery in your static resource, for example, in a zip called res in a subfolder called js and be sure to include it prior to using it.

Zip file with the structure `/res/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js` is referenced from VF as follows:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.res, 'js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js')}"/>
```

Then the JavaScript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    // Whatever function you end up calling to get the data from the page
    function doItToIt() {
        // Get the value of the name field
        yourObj.Name = j$('.name').val();
    }
</script>

<!-- somewhere on your page is your input with styleClass from above jQuery selector -->
<apex:inputfield value="{!myObj.Name}" styleClass="name" />
```

Here you can use styleClass instead of ID since the ID that you specify is not the [ID that will get generated by Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm) and then use the [jQuery val function](http://api.jquery.com/val/).  Just make sure that your styleClass is unique so that the [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) works the way that you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your method can take Apex primitives, collections, typed and generic sObjects, and user-defined Apex classes and interfaces as arguments. Generic sObjects must have an ID or sobjectType value to identify actual type. Interface parameters must have an apexType to identify actual type.
Your method can return Apex primitives, sObjects, collections, user-defined Apex classes and enums, SaveResult, UpsertResult, DeleteResult, SelectOption, or PageReference.

So answering your question

1)Yes remoting can take generic Sobjects with ID or sobjectType Value
2)Yes you can have multiple parameters without overloading
3)Yes i guess acessing dom will be the best practice to get those field values
Document link

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm